# How does spa.UseAngularCliServer() middleware serve a webpage?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, angular-cli

I create a .Net Core 2.1 Angular application with Visual Studio 2017 (ver. 15.7.2)
[image]

I wonder how spa.UseAngularCliServer() serves a page in development mode.

1. In debug mode, there is no "dist" folder in the ClientApp or wwwroot folder, though the webpage is loaded normally.
   Where is the dist folder?
2. It looks like that the spa middleware start an angular-cli dev server, but the webpage is actually hosted by IIS Express.
   How does "ng serve" relate to IIS Express?

Form starup.cs

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Although that's done by proxying requests to the `Angular Development Server` , the proxying is not proxied by IIS , but by ASP.NET Core itself . **IIS has no idea about the port listened by Angular Dev Server** .

1. `UseAngularCliServer("start")` will firstly invoke the command

   ```
   npm start -- --port {dynamic_port}
   ```

The `{dynamic_port}` here is computed at `RunTime` .Since the `npm` command has been already configured in `package.json` , it will then start a dev server by`ng serve -- --port {dynamic_port}` .

2. if the `ng serve` run flawlessly , it will create a plain `HttpClient` for proxy and use it to perform proxy (forward requests to `Angular Dev Server` with the plain `HttpClient` , and copy the response as it's own response) . The `WebSocket` proxy will take place in a similar way .

You can find the source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices) . It's easy to read and understand .

Internally , the `UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start")` will invoke [`AngularCliMiddleware`](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions/AngularCli/AngularCliMiddleware.cs) to do `step 1` and `step 2` . The step 1 is done by :

```
var angularCliServerInfoTask = StartAngularCliServerAsync(sourcePath, npmScriptName, logger);
```

The `StartAngularCliServerAsync` method will find an available TCP port , and run command `npm start -- --port {port}` to start `ng serve` :

```
private static async Task<AngularCliServerInfo> StartAngularCliServerAsync(
    string sourcePath, string npmScriptName, ILogger logger)
{
    var portNumber = TcpPortFinder.FindAvailablePort();
    logger.LogInformation($"Starting @angular/cli on port {portNumber}...");
    var npmScriptRunner = new NpmScriptRunner( sourcePath, npmScriptName, $"--port {portNumber}", null); 
    // ...
}
```

[See the complete code here](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/blob/9c6a1b577f04d845152532c66252811260b3f36a/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions/AngularCli/AngularCliMiddleware.cs#L67)

And the Step 2 is done by :

```
public static void UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer(this ISpaBuilder spaBuilder, Func<Task<Uri>> baseUriTaskFactory)
{
    // ...
    // Proxy all requests to the SPA development server
    applicationBuilder.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        var didProxyRequest = await SpaProxy.PerformProxyRequest( context, neverTimeOutHttpClient, baseUriTaskFactory(), applicationStoppingToken, proxy404s: true);
    });
}
```

The implementation of `PerfromProxyRequest()` can be found [here](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/blob/9c6a1b577f04d845152532c66252811260b3f36a/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions/Proxying/SpaProxy.cs#L75) . For normal requests , It simply forward them using a plain `HttpClient` and copy the response as its own response .

Back to your question :

> Where is the dist folder?

Since you have configured a `spa.UseAngularCliServer("start")`:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
}
```

All those requests will be processed by local dev server launched by angular cli. As a result , there's no `dist` on disk at all . The same will take place if you run the command `ng serve` manually .

> How does "ng serve" relate to IIS Express?

IIS has no idea about the port listened by Angular Dev Server. When there's an incoming message , IIS  just sends it to your ASP.NET Core server . If the request cannot be processed by staticFiles , MVC , or any other middlewares that you've configured before `UseSpa()` , ASP.NET Core will forward it to the Dev Server .

Comment: I have a question. I mistakenly deleted the fold under C:\user\xxxx\Roaming\npm. Does `spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start")` still work?

Comment: @Bigeyes if you `npm` doesn't work, your `spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start")` won't work too.

Comment: @itminus your answer is very clear there are two servers. Then, we should solve CORS issues. Moreover, the API requests from Angular do not include IIS domain, that means the origin of the front end code is the same with the origin of the back end. But, that does not make sense if there are two servers...Have a look please at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58010727/net-localhost-servers-when-creating-angular-react-applications)

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2019, ASP.NET Core 3.1 and `spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");` the node processes started are not terminated when stopping the debbuger. Do you have any ideas why? Every debug results in an `"node"   "\ClientApp\node_modules\.bin\\..\@angular\cli\bin\ng" serve "--port" "59658"` process which is not terminated automatically...

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no need for a dist folder as the files are built and held in-memory by webpack dev server which is used internally by Angular CLI.
2. The requests for the SPA are reverse proxied to the Angular Dev Server by IIS. So IIS receives a request from the browser --> IIS sends a request to angular dev server --> dev server sends data back to IIS --> IIS sends data to browser.