# spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I created a .NET core project with an Angular template and deployed it to my local IIS, and it's working fine.

I want to know the back-end process of

```
spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start")
```

after I deployed to IIS, the angular project the (html/js/css) files are bundled . how angular server started?

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52768852/how-does-spa-useangularcliserver-middleware-serve-a-webpage) might be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you publish your solution into production mode angular will run `ng build --prod` command to generate production code and output everything into dist folder.

Then when we deploy to server like Azure the server will boost your index.html inside your dist folder to run your angular app.

Let me know if you still not clear

Comment: When deployed to IIS/Azure, we didn't need install node js/angular cli right? so how the code start angular cli server?(in development env, we installed node js and angular cli) thanks.

Comment: If you have CI CD like azure devops you can build it to prod mode (including npm install and ng build prod). In Azure cloud Prod mode will not start angular cli server it is just simply serve your index.html to run your web app

Comment: Got it, missing the code if (env.IsDevelopment()){spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");}.  Thanks.