# .Net localhost servers when creating Angular/React applications

Tags: angular, reactjs, asp.net-core

I am using VS2017/2019 and .NET Core 2.1 as to create `Angular` or `React` applications. `Angular-CLI` or `create-react-app` is used for setting everything up. ***All the following has to do with development stage***:

When we build our .NET project, an `IIS express` server is launched as to accommodate our application, let's name it **localhost:19500**.

At the same time when the front-end part is being launched (either Angular or React) a `Webpack Dev server` is launched as well, that accommodates the front-end compiled code in bundles created by Webpack; we can see that by examining (via Chrome Dev Tools) `index.html` which includes these bundles. As to fully understand that, these bundles are not physically located anywhere; they are loaded in memory and are accessible via Webpack Dev Server. If we run the front-end app independently, we can access this Dev server by **localhost:4200** (Angular) or **localhost:3000** (React). So, my question is:

Is my above analysis correct? If we launch IIS server, ***is there any Webpack Dev Server which serves the front-end or the former one serves the front-end bundles***?

If there is a Webpack Dev server, then we have two servers and we should solve CORS issues. If there is not, how IIS takes care of issues like `Hot Module Replacement(HMR)`? What's the exact role of middleware `UseAngularCliServer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment under my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52768852/how-does-spa-useangularcliserver-middleware-serve-a-webpage/52772763#comment102426359_52772763) here, I guess you misunderstood the CORS concept. Quoted from  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) :

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that uses additional HTTP headers to tell **browsers** to give a web application running at one origin, access to selected resources from a different origin.

CORS is used to control the behavior of  **Browser**(or **Browser-like client** , e.g `Electron` ).

---

In this scenario, the **browser** didn't know anything about the Webpack Dev server, so there will be **NO** CORS problems at all:

```
+-------+          +------+               +--------+
|       |          |      |               |        |
|       |          |      |               |        |
|       +---------->      |               |        |
|       |  Request |      +--------------->        |
|       |          |      |               | Kestrel|
|Browser|          | IIS  | Reverse Proxy |        |
|       |Response  |      |               |        |
|       <----------+      <---------------+        |
|       |          |      |               |                   +-------------+
|       |          |      |               |  For Spa Requests:|             |
|       |          |      |               |  -----------------> Webpack Dev |
|       |          |      |               |        |  Proxy   |  Server     |
|       |          |      |               |        <----------+             |
+-------+          -------+               +--------+          +-------------+
```

1. **The browser only talks to IIS**. And then `IIS` proxies the requests to your ASP.NET Core `Kestrel` server(since you're using `ASP.NET Core 2.1`, I assume it's running in [out-of-process mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2#out-of-process-hosting-model)).
2. Be aware **it is your `Kestrel` server who sends the requests to Webpack Dev Server**. Your `Kestrel` acts as a proxy and forwards related requests to Webpack Dev Server when in Development environment.

As you can see, the browser sends all its traffic to `IIS` and also gets all the responses from `IIS`. The browser knows only one server , i.e. IIS .

Also, IIS has no idea about the HMR. When developer accesses this SPA page, there's a **WebSocket connection** set up between your browser and `IIS`. `IIS` just forwards it to `Kestrel`. And then `Kestrel` forwards it to your `Webpack Dev Server`. When developer changes the source code of SPA, the file `watcher` will notify the browser to reload dynamically.

---

**[Edit]** :
To answer your answer question

> Is it possible to find the port on which Webpack Dev Server is launched? localhost:xxxx

This port is computed dynamically at run-time. ASP.NET Core doesn't expose an API for developer to access it. But as a **walkaround** to know the port number, you can find it in your **log** information.

For example, I'm using VS Code to debug the App:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to find the port on which Webpack Dev Server is launched? `localhost:xxxx`

Comment: @Unknowndeveloper  I've updated my answer to show how to find the port in the log. Please check.