# Getting error "npm ERR! missing script: start" after upgrading to .Net 3.0

Tags: node.js, angular, asp.net-core, npm

The original code running on ASP.Net Core 2.2 (upgraded from 2.1) didn't have start in package.json.

https://github.com/TrilonIO/aspnetcore-angular-universal/blob/master/package.json

When updating to ASP.Net Core 3.0, it is now looking for start script.

Why is it looking for start now?

> ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The NPM
>   script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was
>   listening for requests. The error output was: npm ERR! missing script:
>   start

This is what is in the log:

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok 1 verbose cli [
>   '/project/.nvm/versions/node/v10.8.0/bin/node', 1 verbose cli
>   '/project/.nvm/versions/node/v10.8.0/bin/npm', 1 verbose cli   'run',
>   1 verbose cli   'start', 1 verbose cli   '--', 1 verbose cli
>   '--port', 1 verbose cli   '54294' ] 2 info using npm@6.4.1 3 info
>   using node@v10.8.0 4 verbose stack Error: missing script: start 4
>   verbose stack     at run
>   (/project/.nvm/versions/node/v10.8.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/run-script.js:155:19)
>   4 verbose stack     at
>   /project/.nvm/versions/node/v10.8.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/run-script.js:63:5
>   4 verbose stack     at
>   /project/.nvm/versions/node/v10.8.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:115:5
>   4 verbose stack     at
>   /project/.nvm/versions/node/v10.8.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:418:5
>   4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_
>   (/project/.nvm/versions/node/v10.8.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:373:45)
>   4 verbose stack     at final
>   (/project/.nvm/versions/node/v10.8.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:416:3)
>   4 verbose stack     at then
>   (/project/.nvm/versions/node/v10.8.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:160:5)
>   4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.
>   (/project/.nvm/versions/node/v10.8.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:332:20)
>   4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.callback
>   (/project/.nvm/versions/node/v10.8.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16)
>   4 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete]
>   (fs.js:233:13) 5 verbose cwd
>   /project/Dropbox/Workspace/MyProject/src/MyProject.Web/ClientApp 6
>   verbose Darwin 19.0.0 7 verbose argv
>   "/project/.nvm/versions/node/v10.8.0/bin/node"
>   "/project/.nvm/versions/node/v10.8.0/bin/npm" "run" "start" "--"
>   "--port" "54294" 8 verbose node v10.8.0 9 verbose npm  v6.4.1 10 error
>   missing script: start 11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

This is what is reported on the console:

> ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end
>   of the stream.    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(String
>   sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(String
>   sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean
>   waitCompletionNotification)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.<>c.b__2_0(Task`1
>   task)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__274_0(Object obj)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread
>   threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread
>   threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task&
>   currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean
>   waitCompletionNotification)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Util.TaskTimeoutExtensions.WithTimeout[T](Task`1
>   task, TimeSpan timeoutDelay, String message)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Proxy.SpaProxy.PerformProxyRequest(HttpContext
>   context, HttpClient httpClient, Task`1 baseUriTask, CancellationToken
>   applicationStoppingToken, Boolean proxy404s)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SpaProxyingExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.HandleException(HttpContext
>   context, ExceptionDispatchInfo edi) fail:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
>         Connection id "0HLS17GG2QFU7", Request id "0HLS17GG2QFU7:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the
>   application. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
>   (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without
>   indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error
>   output was: npm ERR! missing script: start

Comment: How you are staring Angular application?

Comment: The project is part of a .Net project, so it is started with "dotnet run".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When updating to ASP.Net Core 3.0, it is now looking for start script.

In my opinion,it is always necessary if you start with only `dotnet run` for an integrated angular + asp.net core project.

You need to configure `spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");` to run angular

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
});
```

which will firstly invoke the command

```
npm start -- --port {dynamic_port}
```

npm looks in your package.json file, and if you have  script: start ,something like

```
"scripts": { "start": "ng serve" }
```

then it will do `ng serve -- --port {dynamic_port}`. If npm can't find your start script, it defaults to `node server.js`

Refer to [How does spa.UseAngularCliServer() middleware serve a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52768852/how-does-spa-useangularcliserver-middleware-serve-a-webpage/52772763#52772763)