# Angular 9 component and .NET Core application not running as SPA

Tags: c#, single-page-application, asp.net-core-3.1, angular9

I created an Asp.Net Core 3.1 MVC project in Visual Studio 2019 then created a new angular client app using Angular 9 (following this [tutorial](https://www.infoq.com/articles/Angular-Core-3/)). I was able to see my angular component running within my View when I ran the client and server separately. I then modified my startup.cs to include running the SPA so that I could run them at the same time.

```cs
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            if (!env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "angularApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
```

This line `spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");` does fire but nothing seems to happen.

Here is my package.json

```json
{
  "name": "angular-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/elements": "^9.1.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/material": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.0-rc.0",
    "document-register-element": "^1.7.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.0-rc.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  }
}
```

.csproj file

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <SpaRoot>angularApp\</SpaRoot>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>

    <!-- Set this to true if you enable server-side prerendering -->
    <BuildServerSideRenderer>false</BuildServerSideRenderer>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="wwwroot\images\Symbols\A.png" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\images\Symbols\B.png" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\images\Symbols\C.png" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\images\Symbols\D.png" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\images\Symbols\E.png" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\images\Symbols\F.png" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\images\Symbols\G.png" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\images\Symbols\H.png" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\images\Symbols\I.png" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\images\Symbols\J.png" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\images\Symbols\K.png" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\images\Symbols\L.png" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\images\Symbols\Letters.ai" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\images\Symbols\M.png" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\images\Symbols\N.png" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\images\Symbols\O.png" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\images\Symbols\P.png" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\images\Symbols\Q.png" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\images\Symbols\R.png" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\images\Symbols\S.png" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\images\Symbols\T.png" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\images\Symbols\U.png" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\images\Symbols\V.png" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\images\Symbols\W.png" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\images\Symbols\X.png" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\images\Symbols\Y.png" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\images\Symbols\Z.png" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="3.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices" Version="3.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="3.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild" Version="3.8.3">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Don't publish the SPA source files, but do show them in the project files list -->
    <Content Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
    <None Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
    <None Include="$(SpaRoot)**" Exclude="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="angularApp\src\app\common\common.ts" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="angularApp\src\app\services\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
    <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
    <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
    </Exec>
    <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --prod" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:ssr -- --prod" Condition=" '$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true' " />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**; $(SpaRoot)dist-server\**" />
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" Condition="'$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true'" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

[image: Project Files]

Can someone let me know what I'm missing? 
Thanks!

Comment: try this https://medium.com/@YvonneFPan/how-to-integrate-angular-9-with-a-asp-net-core-project-cb37d9da7197

Comment: Try to run "ng build" from terminal to see what’s happening

Comment: any chance you sorted this on your own?  I'm running into a similar issue right now. Have you tried https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17277

Comment: sorry no luck yet... I ended up having to go with Angular 8.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52768852/how-does-spa-useangularcliserver-middleware-serve-a-webpage

Answer (score 3):

Change:
`"start": "ng serve"`

To:`"start": "echo hello && ng serve"`

This issue explained well [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17277)

Answer (score 0):

After upgrade to Angular 9, change following items:

1. Remove following line from **ClientApp/src/main.ts**:

   export { renderModule, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
2. Replace **"start": "ng serve",** in **ClientApp/package.json** with:
   **"start": "echo Running... && ng serve",**

Same changes are applicible for Angular 10.